# Call C++ dll from with Delphi

Tags: c++, delphi

My goal is to call a function written in C++ (with a C interface) from within Delphi (RAD Studio XE6). In the end, the dll will be generated by Visual Studio 2013, but I've tried to start with generating the Dll from RAD Studio XE6.

So, I have created a Dll project in Rad Studio (Using VC++ style Dll). The file is here

```
#include <vcl.h>
#include <windows.h>

#pragma hdrstop
#pragma argsused

int WINAPI DllEntryPoint(HINSTANCE hinst, unsigned long reason, void* lpReserved)
{
    return 1;
}

extern "C" int next(int n) {
    return n + 1;
}
```

It compiles as a Dll. On the Delphi side, the code is as below:

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils, Windows;
function next(a: Int32): Int32; cdecl;
  external 'Project3.dll';
var
  a: Int32;
begin
  try
    a := 3;
    Writeln('Hello world!', next(a));
    sleep(3000);
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```

The project does compile but does not run. It gives the following error:

```
*** A stack buffer overrun occurred in "C:\...\Debug\Project1.exe"
```

It fails on the following assembly line

```
mov eax,[edi]
```

I have tried to change cdecl to std call, pascal or register. But nothing works.

Solution: Thanks to Rudy, the following code does work. First the C++ side:

```
#include <vcl.h>
#include <windows.h>

#pragma hdrstop
#pragma argsused

int WINAPI DllEntryPoint(HINSTANCE hinst, unsigned long reason, void* lpReserved)
{
    return 1;
}

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int __stdcall next(int n) {
    return n + 1;
}
```

and then the Delphi side.

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils, Windows;
function next(a: Int32): Int32; stdcall;
  external 'Project3.dll';
var
  a: Int32;
begin
  try
    a := 3;
    Writeln('Hello world!', next(a));
    sleep(3000);
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```

Comment: That's not really a C++ export, the function is using the C-calling convention. Maybe add `extern "C"`? C++ is not likely to be supported by Delphi, usually plain C functions are the lowest common denominator that can be imported by any other language.

Comment: @sashoalm: Thanks. I have tried that and updated my question. But it does not work either.

Comment: @InsideLoop You should first make sure you can load and call your DLL function from a C or C++ program before trying to do this with Delphi.

Comment: Are you sure the function is exported? It doesn't look like it. Take a look with a tool like Dependency Walker. If not, read the online help on how to export functions. I guess that a simple directive should be enough, e.g. __declspec(dllexport) or __export or some such.

Comment: FWIW, take a look at [this article of mine](http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-cppobjs.html).

Comment: @InsideLoop - Also, you should really use Windows API types such as `LONG`, `DWORD`, etc., and not C++ types such as `int`.  There is no guarantee that `int` will be 32 bits, as C++ makes no such guarantees.  In addition, the name you exported is mangled -- as the other comment suggested, take a look at your exported function using Dependency Walker.

Comment: @Rudy: Thanks a lot. I finally managed to make it work. The working code is shown in the question.

Comment: @Paul `int` is fine. Always signed 32 bit on Windows

Comment: @InsideLoop: where in the question?

Comment: @Paul: unlike pointers, `int` is always `int32_t`, on Windows, both in Win32 and Win64. That is the model Windows uses. There are other models, e.g used by OS X or Linux. See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing#64-bit_data_models)

Comment: @Rudy: In my first post, I gave the solution to my question. I have discovered tdump to give me useful information about the dll. Now I have some problems linking the Delphi code with a C++ dll compiled with Visual Studio. The __stdcall convention makes VisualStudio mangle the name from next to _next@4. If I use __cdecl, it does not mangle the name but I can't call it from Delphi, even using cdecl;

Comment: @InsideLoop - You need to build the DLL using a module definition (.DEF) file.  This will unmangle the name.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d91k01sh.aspx

Comment: Either use a .def file, as Paul said, or try the name with a _ (singe underscore) prefix. I don't know for sure, but it would not surprise me if VC++ had a way to give the export name directly in the code. I am not too familiar with VC++. .def files are pretty easy to use. See my article, near the end: "Differences in name decoration".

Comment: dllexport with cdecl and extern "C" has no decoration. And yes you can use cdecl on the delphi side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't exporting the function. Do that like this:

```
extern "C" 
{
    __declspec(dllexport) int next(int n)
    {
        return n + 1;
    }
}
```

Using `extern "C"`, `__declspec(dllexport)` and the default calling convention of `__cdecl` will lean to the function being exported undecorated. Any other choice leads to decoration.

On the Delphi side it is:

```
function next(a: Integer): Integer; cdecl;
  external '...';
```

Decoration is not such a bad thing but if you want to use `stdcall`, and avoid decoration, then you should use a .def file to export the function.

Comment: It does not work. I have tried to do it that way, and tdump -ee library.dll tells me that next has been exported but the Delphi application crashes when it runs. But if I compile it with RAD Studio XE6, it works fine. Have you ever managed to mix code coming from Visual Studio 2013 and Delphi XE6?

Comment: It works fine. I don't know what you have got wrong. "Crashes" gives no information.

Comment: It says: "The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000a200). Click OK to close the application.". And then it breaks at "mov ex,[edi]". So you know, I have created my Dll with Visual Studio 2013 using: New Project->Visual C++->DLL (Windows). Could you please confirm that you have compiled the C++ code with Visual Studio?

Comment: I'm not compiling anything. The error code is STATUS_NOT_APPCONTAINER. Are you building a WinRT DLL? A Windows Store DLL.

Comment: I have no idea (I am more of a Unix guy). How do we know that? Should I create a WinRT Dll or not? What kind of Dll should I create?. (The Project says: DLL(Windows): A project for a native dynamic-link library (DLL) that can be used by a Windows app or runtime component.)

Comment: You don't want anything to do with WinRT. We can't see you code anymore though. It's changed. You aren't including vcl.h in you VS version.

Comment: It **works** at last :-). Thank you very much for your help. I have just created an MFC DLL with the same code. Is it the right thing to do?

Comment: I don't see any reason to include MFC. A plain Win32 DLL project should be fine.

Comment: I know why I hate Windows :-) I just can't find any template that says "Plain Dll" in Visual Studio 2013. I only have MFC DLL and DLL (Windows) which is a WinRT Dll.

Comment: @InsideLoop - I build plain DLL's just fine in Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: You want a Win32 project. Then, select DLL in one of the sub choices.